# Let logged-in users use radio buttons (yes and no) to exclude their author profile from the user listing

Tags: users

I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction because I am stuck when it comes to solving the following issue.

So I have a directory listing of WordPress users (http://192.99.201.241/~alumni/alumni-directory/). I use get_users query to output users. I would like to create a function, which will give logged-in users ability to choose whether they would like to be included/excluded from the directory listing.

Any assistance would be helpful.

Comment: Th correct element for a boolean (yes/no) decision is a **checkbox**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add a meta key and value [to each user first](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/users/working-with-user-metadata/) and then add `meta_key` and `meta_value` to the get_users argument array.

Your meta key could for example be called `showme` and value would be `"yes"`. So wherever an author has a meta value of `"no"`, `get_users()` would exclude that author.

**Add this code to your *functions.php*:**

```
<?php // you might not need this line when pasting into functions.php
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'so_show_extra_radios' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'so_show_extra_radios' );

function so_show_extra_radios( $user ) { ?>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="showme">Show profile</label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="showme" value="yes" <?php 
                    if (esc_attr(get_the_author_meta('showme', $user->ID)) == "yes")
                        echo "checked";
                ?>></input> Yes<br>
                <input type="radio" name="showme" value="no" <?php 
                    if (esc_attr(get_the_author_meta('showme', $user->ID)) == "no")
                        echo "checked";
                ?>></input>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php }

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'so_save_profile' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'so_save_profile' );

function so_save_profile( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) return false;

    if (wp_kses_post( $_POST['showme'] ) == 'yes')
        update_usermeta( absint( $user_id ), 'showme', "yes" );
    else
        update_usermeta( absint( $user_id ), 'showme', "no" );
}
```

Then add your `meta_key` and `meta_value` arguments in your author.php (or wherever you retrieve your author profiles) [as described here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users).

Comment: It's completely edited in, check it out